# Using Ionic with Breeze JS

Tags: breeze, ionic-framework

Is it possible to use breezeJS with Ionic framework(mibile), As i am planing to develop mobile  application using Ionic and am targeting using ionic but i would love if Ionic support the use of BreezeJS, If anyone have an idea, please share your experience.

Thanks.`

Answer (score 1):

BreezeJs works very well with angular, there is an angular adapter that breeze provides with it.

Since ionic is built on Angular, ionic also will work well with breeze. I built a complex ionic app that makes very heavy use of breezeJs especially for caching data to work offline.

Comment: Good day, could you please help me with the solution to this, i can get breezejs to work with ionic, Even after inject breeze as a dependency to app.js file 'breeze.angular',    // configures breeze for an angular app
    'breeze.directives' // contains the breeze validation directive (zValidate), I cant get it to work.